# How can I fix this index error?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

> Well this is the code I have written so far

```
import csv
file = open("gardeningJobs.txt", "r")
read= csv.reader(file)
ls=list(read)
file.close()
print(ls)


total=0
status = " A"
for line in ls:
    if (int(line[3] - int(line[4]) = 0):
        total += int(line[4])
        print(total)
```

> The error occures in this line of code if (int(line[3] - int(line[4]) = 0):

1234, 27/02/2016, A56, 125, Q, 0
1235, 27/02/2016, A26, 250, A, 125
1236, 27/02/2016, A36, 300, N, 0
1237, 27/02/2016, A55, 170, Q, 0
1238, 28/02/2016, A59, 90, A, 90
1240, 28/02/2016, A60, 260, A, 120

> This is the 2D array that goes with it in a file

Please any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: You probably need to wrap your line[3] (e.g if int(line[3]) - int(line[4]) == 0 )  Note the remove of the outer () and using equivalence as opposed to assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be this:

```
if int(line[3]) - int(line[4]) == 0:
```

`==` instead of `=` and `int(line[3])`.